# By a RadGridView, how can I get to show detail information?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, telerik

I have created a hierarchical relationship in a RadGridView. But the relationship doesn't work. I can't show the detail information. What do I do wrong?

If I generated automatically all relationships works fine. But I need just one field of one table as detail info.

Further: I use VS2013 Prof., WinForms as UI and LINQ to SQL as datasource.

The source code is:

```
    private void OpenConfigurations()
    {
          bsConfigurations.DataSource = Db.Configurations.Where(c => c.Active == true && c.CompanyId == CurrentCompany.CompanyId).Select(c => c).OrderBy(c => c.Name);
          bsConfigurationContracts.DataSource = Db.ConfigurationContracts.Where(c => c.Contract.InsurranceId == CurrentCompany.CompanyId).Select(c =>
        c).OrderBy(c => c.Contract.Name);

          GridViewRelation gvrConfigurations = new GridViewRelation();
          gvrConfigurations.ChildColumnNames.Add("ConfigurationId");
          gvrConfigurations.ChildTemplate = this.gridViewTemplate1;
          gvrConfigurations.ParentColumnNames.Add("ConfigurationId");
          gvrConfigurations.ParentTemplate = this.gvConfiguration.MasterTemplate;
          gvConfiguration.Relations.Add(gvrConfigurations);
}
```

In the designer:

```
this.gridViewTemplate1.AllowAddNewRow = false;
gridViewTextBoxColumn1.EnableExpressionEditor = false;
gridViewTextBoxColumn1.FieldName = "Contract.Name";
gridViewTextBoxColumn1.HeaderText = "Name";
gridViewTextBoxColumn1.Name = "colName";
gridViewTextBoxColumn1.Width = 250;
gridViewTextBoxColumn2.EnableExpressionEditor = false;
gridViewTextBoxColumn2.FieldName = "ConfigurationId";
gridViewTextBoxColumn2.HeaderText = "ConfigurationId";
gridViewTextBoxColumn2.IsVisible = false;
gridViewTextBoxColumn2.Name = "colConfigurationId";

this.gridViewTemplate1.Columns.AddRange(new Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewDataColumn[] { gridViewTextBoxColumn1, gridViewTextBoxColumn2 });
this.gridViewTemplate1.DataSource = this.bsConfigurationContracts;
// 
// gvConfiguration
// 
this.gvConfiguration.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(233)))), ((int)(((byte)(240)))), ((int)(((byte)(249)))));
this.gvConfiguration.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
this.gvConfiguration.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.gvConfiguration.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F);
this.gvConfiguration.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
this.gvConfiguration.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl;
this.gvConfiguration.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 30);
// 
// 
// 
this.gvConfiguration.MasterTemplate.AllowAddNewRow = false;
this.gvConfiguration.MasterTemplate.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
gridViewTextBoxColumn3.EnableExpressionEditor = false;
gridViewTextBoxColumn3.FieldName = "Name";
gridViewTextBoxColumn3.HeaderText = "Name";
gridViewTextBoxColumn3.Name = "colName";
gridViewTextBoxColumn3.SortOrder = Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadSortOrder.Ascending;
gridViewTextBoxColumn3.Width = 250;
gridViewTextBoxColumn4.EnableExpressionEditor = false;
gridViewTextBoxColumn4.FieldName = "ConfigurationId";
gridViewTextBoxColumn4.HeaderText = "ConfigurationId";
gridViewTextBoxColumn4.IsVisible = false;
gridViewTextBoxColumn4.Name = "colConfigurationId";
this.gvConfiguration.MasterTemplate.Columns.AddRange(new Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewDataColumn[] { gridViewTextBoxColumn3, gridViewTextBoxColumn4 });
this.gvConfiguration.MasterTemplate.DataSource = this.bsConfigurations;
sortDescriptor1.PropertyName = "colName";
this.gvConfiguration.MasterTemplate.SortDescriptors.AddRange(new Telerik.WinControls.Data.SortDescriptor[] { sortDescriptor1 });
this.gvConfiguration.MasterTemplate.Templates.AddRange(new Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewTemplate[] { this.gridViewTemplate1 });
this.gvConfiguration.Name = "gvConfiguration";
this.gvConfiguration.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
this.gvConfiguration.ShowGroupPanel = false;
this.gvConfiguration.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1098, 72);
this.gvConfiguration.TabIndex = 4;
this.gvConfiguration.Text = "radGridView1";
this.gvConfiguration.CellDoubleClick += new Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventHandler(this.gvConfiguration_CellDoubleClick);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in the relation you have to add the column name in stead of the field name.

So this is the right code:

```
GridViewRelation gvrConfigurations = new GridViewRelation();
          gvrConfigurations.ChildColumnNames.Add("colConfigurationId");
          gvrConfigurations.ChildTemplate = this.gridViewTemplate1;
          gvrConfigurations.ParentColumnNames.Add("colConfigurationId");
          gvrConfigurations.ParentTemplate = this.gvConfiguration.MasterTemplate;
          gvConfiguration.Relations.Add(gvrConfigurations);
```